# "every" + possessive + noun

Tags: possessives, determiners, old-english, contemporary-english

I naively asked a question about [the use of "every" with possessives](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/295822/every-your-thought-or-every-thought-of-yours-or-every-one-of-your-thoughts) on the ELL thinking there will be a very simple answer. I was pretty sure that saying either

> *Every your thought* is important to me.

or

> *Every thought of yours* is important to me.

was just a matter of language register. Well, it seems to be a matter of the age you live in! Thanks to some helpful comments I was amazed to discover that ***"every" + possessive + noun*** was [grammatical in Early Modern English, apparently present in Shakespeare](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/205815/my-every-word-or-every-my-word). I must say I couldn't find examples of it in Shakespeare, neither in the KJV Bible, but in other old books that don't exist on the net. However, I did find it on the internet in a text from Medieval times (1480 approx.):

> A century and a half later, the *Northumberland Household Book* prescribes: "Whensoever any of his Lordeship Servauntes be comaunded to ride on message in Winter...that every of theym be allowed for the tyme for his being furth in his jomay... for every meall and for ***every his baiting***; and for his Hors every day and night of his saide jornay, ..." (*[Medieval Panorama](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Medieval_Panorama/-aRYk3mRD3wC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22every%20his%22&pg=PA324&printsec=frontcover)*, G. G. Coulton)

So this use must have been grammatical in Old English.

My question is: Does anyone know how ***"every" + possessive + noun*** shifted from being *grammatical* in Old English *to not grammatical* in Modern English? Is there any information on the evolution of this use of "every"?

Comment: We do not say "every your thought", although we do say "your every thought" instead.  (Do not try to find logic behind it.)

Comment: Check out page 593 of [The Handbook of Contemporary Syntactic Theory](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22His+every+book+In+other+words%2C+the+lack+of+overt%22), which to my mind strongly suggests that the early usage you're referring to simply echoed the syntax of other European languages (and perhaps *Latin*), at a time when English itself was probably syntactically quite primitive / indeterminate.

Comment: I see you asked much the same question last year: [Which expression is stronger? “My every attempt” or “every attempt of mine”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/554118/which-expression-is-stronger-my-every-attempt-or-every-attempt-of-mine)

Comment: Two of the most common words to occur after ***every his...*** are ***...child*** and ***...children***, with the sense that would normally be conveyed today by ***all his children***. This is the kind of concept that's commonly referenced in ***wills*** and related legal texts. And as with religious texts, legal texts are *very slow* to reflect changes in mainstream language, which explains why NGrams shows the usage as far from uncommon in Victorian times even though it's very unfamiliar to the modern ear. (We might still read Dickens, but few of us read Victorian wills and such! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers The other question is not about "every my attempt", but about "my every attempt". Thank you for all the information, the mist seems to dissipate somehow.

Comment: Well, as you say in your question text here, *it seems to be a matter of the age you live in!* And you did originally write ***Every my** attempt was doomed to fail* as your example text in that earlier question. So I assumed that *at that time* you'd seen the now-invalid sequence in Victorian texts, and simply didn't realise that we don't use that form any more, until it was pointed out in comments.

Comment: ...note that even the "modern" form ***my every attempt*** isn't particularly natural in conversational contexts today. It's literary / poetic, somewhat dated, and probably best avoided unless you have a *very* good reason for not using the everyday plural construction ***all my attempts***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I guess I was rather confused about the whole matter... I just bumped into this structure again, and the confusions resurfaced. Thanks to your helpful comments  I understand better now, so thanks.

Comment: As should be obvious, I'm *not* suggesting this is a duplicate of your previous question. In principle I think I could have answered the earlier one myself. But the best I can do with this one is give a few pointers in a comment, and hope that spurs someone more knowledgeable than us to give a more coherent explanation of how this syntactic shift came about.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I wouldn't underestimate your knowledge. Everything you have said here is definitely more than I know about all this, so I would welcome it as an answer, either here, or to my other question. But no pressure, my goal is to learn whether it is through comments or answers. It would just be nice to reward your effort. And yes, my work constantly involves antiquated texts and language, so if I can find an older usage that is still comprehensible today, I will employ it! But I am glad to discover that this one is plain ungrammatical today. I'll definitely avoid it.

Comment: As for "my every attempt", literary and poetic are qualities I always welcome, so I'll probably switch to that :)

Comment: Are you sure that this sample is an example of the phenomenon you're referring to?  The phrasing here is "for every his baiting", which, given the context, might suggest that "for every" traveler an allowance for bedding was to be made.  I don't know that it necessarily means "every bedding of" some person's.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't agree that that form is poetic or somewhat dated. For example, here is an example from [today's NY Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2022/07/04/sports/tennis/roger-federer-wimbledon-return.html): "The crowd on Centre Court swayed and swooned with his every move." It's still used often.

Comment: Yes, there are some fixed phrases like that. But in general determiners can't overlap, so you can't have a quantifier like _every_ before an article like _the_ or a possessive like _my_.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan: Oh, come on! Surely you can see that poetic / alliterative / dated ***swayed and swooned*** in your cited example is a pretty strong hint that the *entire text* is more than a trifle "affected".

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's pretty much a straight news (sports) article, and there are many other examples that don't use alliteration. But this seems to be a matter of opinion, so I think it's fine if we disagree.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan: <swoons>

Answer (score 1):

> I was amazed to discover that "every" + possessive + noun was grammatical in Early Modern English, apparently present in Shakespeare.

Yes, but "every" is used as a **pronoun** in your example:

> for *every* meall and for *every* his *baiting*;

= for *everyone*, meal (crushed/ground cereal) and for *everyone*, his baiting (food supplies);

In
"*Every your thought is important to me." every is a **determiner** and cannot modify another determiner (your)

"Your every (individual) thought is important to me." every is an **adjective**.

Comment: Olofssohn (Every₃ in OED: A grammatically neglected determiner ...
Nordic Journal of English Studies) offers an alternative analysis: ' _every_ ... can take a postdeterminer
(or adjectival?) position after a genitive (including possessives).  Previously, 'In order to
cover examples such as “his every whim”, COBUILD (alone) makes an
ad hoc reclassification of _every_ and labels it “adjective”.' [As the article addresses the OED classification, the (alone) caveat probably means (alone among other works).]